# Sampling from the joint distribution p(x,y) when y = f(x)

Tags: sampling, joint-distribution, gibbs

Suppose I want to sample from the joint distribution $p(X, Y)$, where $X$ is a random variable and $Y = f(X)$ where $f$ is a known function of $X$. However, sampling from $p(X,Y)$ directly is hard. Could I use Gibbs sampling and sample from the conditionals $x^{(k)} \sim p(X\mid Y=y^{(k-1)})$ with $y^{(k-1)}=f(x^{(k-1)})$ and $y^{(k)} \sim p(Y\mid X=x^{(k)}) = \delta(y-f(x^{(k)}))$ for $k = 1, 2, \dots$? Would this Gibbs sampler converge?

Comment: Sampling from $p(X,Y)$ directly is *easy*: sample $X$ and compute $Y=f(X)$.

Comment: This would work if I could decompose $f(X, Y) = f(Y|X)f(X)$. But I do not know the marginal $f(X)$.

Comment: I do not follow that at all.  If you can draw values from $X$, then you can draw values from $f(X)$ by applying $f$ to them.  According to your description, the recipe I gave is practically the only way to draw values from $(X,Y)$, and it's computationally optimal, because any method to draw from $(X,Y)$ in any manner yields draws from $X$ (by ignoring $Y$) and having the $Y$-values amounts to computing $f(X)$ for each draw.  Note that the joint distribution is singular: it does not have a density.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the marginal $p(X) = \int p(X, Y)dY$, not the the function $f(X)$. I know how to compute $f(X)$ given $X$. But I do not have the marginal $p(X)$.

Comment: I made a confusion with letters $p$ and $f$.

Comment: You couldn't possibly even get started if you didn't have *some* information about the marginal of $X$.  Please tell us what information you do have.  (Hint: $f$ doesn't give you any information at all.)

Comment: $p(X,Y)$ is singular in $R^2$, but it has a density in $R^1$, doesn't it? I will be more specific about my problem. Suppose I have the following fixed point equation $x = f(x)$ and then I add a random error $E$, i.e., $x = f(x)+E$ with  $p(E)$ known. Now $X$ is an r.v. and $Y=f(X)$ too. Can I sample from $p(X)$ by calling $Y=f(X)$ and then using Gibbs sampling to sample from $p(X,Y)$?

Comment: It's still not evident what you are doing, because "$x=f(x)+E$" makes no sense.  If $x$ is a real number, then the equation $x=f(x)$ generically describes a discrete subset of real numbers. For instance, with $f(x)=x^2$, the equation $x=f(x)$ determines the numbers $0$ and $1$--that's all. What is the addition of $E$ attempting to model?

Comment: Thank you for you comments, I will think a bit more in my problem.

Answer (score 1):

(This answer does not really help with the Gibbs sampler much, but points at something else you could do. I do think the Gibbs sampler would converge).

Recall that, 
$$p(X,Y) = p(Y | X) p(X)\, . $$

Now if you can sample from the marginal of $X$, then $X$ is the [linchpin variable](http://users.stat.umn.edu/~galin/AHJ.pdf). You can use exact sampling methods if it is a known distribution, or you could use MCMC. This sampler should intuitively converge faster than the Gibbs sampler because the Markov chain is only present in $X$ here, whereas in the Gibbs sampler, the Markov chain samples both $(X, Y)$.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. The problem is that I do not know the marginal $p(X)$. I know the conditional $p(X|Y)$, i.e., for fixed $Y = y$, I know how to sample $X$. And for fixed $X = x$, I can compute $Y = f(X)$.